# How to create outline tree in PDF generated from HTML using Flying saucer Itext JAVA?

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

How to create outline tree for a PDF generated from HTML using iText (V.5) JAVA ?
The outline tree is bookmark tree.
I want all headers in my HTML to be nodes in my Outline tree.
So it will be like:

```
H1
-H2
--H3
---H4
```

And so.
Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer some where on other site can't remember, but it was similar to this answer :
[Bookmarks with xhtmlrenderer (iText)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266908/bookmarks-with-xhtmlrenderer-itext)
So any body faces this issue refer this answer.